Container intended for horizontal scroll makes the whole content wider
I have a container which i want to take up remaining space of maximally max-w-7xl (tailwind), and its flexbox, there is overflow-x-auto set, but the whole content on the page is wider, and there is no scrollbar.
    <TabsList
        ref={scrollRef}
        className="overflow-auto mb-8 gap-2 flex items-center justify-start"
      >
        <MyTabsTrigger
          activeTab={activeTab}
        >

